# Number of ways to construct a 4 digit pin code, under some conditions

Tags: combinatorics

Given the digits $0,1,...,9$, the numer of possibilities to construct a PIN code is $10^4$ (zero can be at the beginning since it's a code and not a number).

**I need to find the number of PIN codes that have at least two of the same digits.**

I tried using two ways to calculate, but got different results and I could really use some help figuring out why it happend.

**First solution:**

The number of PIN codes with all distinct digits is $10\times9\times8\times7$. So the number of PIN codes with at least two of the same digits should be $10^4 - 10\times9\times8\times7 = 4960$.

**Second solution:**

If a PIN code has at least two of the same digits, it has exactly two, three or four of the same digits.

For having exactly two of the same digits, I have $10$ choices for what digits should be the same. I then choose their position in the code, ${4 \choose 2}$ choices for that , and then there are $9\times8$ choices for the other two digits. All in all, there are $10\times{4 \choose 2}\times8\times9=4320$ possibilities for that.

For having exactly three of the same digits, again there are $10$ choices for what digits should be the same. For choosing their position in the code there are ${4 \choose 3}$ ways, and $9$ ways to pick the fourth digit. So there are $10\times{4 \choose 3}\times9 = 360$ possibilities for that.

Lastly, the number of possible ways to construct a PIN code with exactly 4 of the same digits is $10$, which is trivial $(0000,1111,...,9999)$.

Summing up all of the above, we get that the number of possibilities is $4320+360+10 = 4690$.

I could really use some help figuring out why one (or both) of my methods is wrong.

Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't $0000$ have only _one_ distinct digit? You have totally misinterpreted the question.

Comment: Hi, my apologies, since English is not my main language I totally misinterpreted the meaning of the word distinct. I edited it, hope it makes sence now.

Comment: You missed the case where you have two pairs, for example 1122 or 3443.

Comment: I see. But when I calculate the amount of pairs I get ${4 \choose 2}\times 10\times9 = 540$. If I add this up, then I get more than I should. What did I do wrong here?

Comment: No pairs give you $270$ and not $540$. You are double counting.

Comment: Could you elaborate more please? How do I get to 270 pairs?

Comment: Say you choose $1$ and the next number is $2$. Your $4C2$ will count 1 2 1 2,  2 1 2 1 and so on. Now when the first number is $2$ and the next number is $1$, you again count them.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so thanks for the help guys, it turns out I wasn't counting pairs of the same digit.
The way I calculated it:

We have $10\times9$ choices for the two pairs of identical digits. Next, we need to find out how many possibilities are there to divide them to pairs. This is much like dividng $2n$ people to pairs, when $n=2$.

All in all we get: $10\times9\times\frac{4!}{2^{2}\times2!} = 270$.

Summing this with the above we get $270+4690=4960$, which is the correct answer.